# Opam not getting latest packages

Tags: ocaml, opam

I just installed opam using the quick install
http://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Quick_Install.html

I now have

```
$opam --version
1.1.0
```

which is current.  I ran "opam update" and "opam upgrade" to get the latest packages.  However, when I install packages, it is still giving me the old versions (such as core 109.42 instead of core 109.55):

```
$ opam search core
Available packages for 4.01.0:
async_core          109.42.00  Monadic concurrency library
```

What do I need to do to get opam to give me the latest libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you previously built from source, make sure you uninstall that first.  For whatever reason, even though the opam version correctly reports "1.1.0", it was still using the old repo address.  After you uninstall old opam entirely, then follow the installation instructions at the link above.

You will know you succeeded when you do "opam update" and prints:

```
default    Downloading http://opam.ocamlpro.com/urls.txt
[NOTE] The repository 'default' will be *permanently* redirected to https://opam.ocaml.org (opam-version >= "1.1.0")
```